# Using backward chaining in graphDB

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, graphdb

I have created an ontology and now I want to use backward chaining in graphDB. I'm pretty new to this and I actually have no clue on where to start. How do I perform backward chaining in graphDB?

I have a little bit of experience with graphDB but no experience with backward chaining.

Comment: I doubt that you can force any backward chaining in GraphDB - at least I don't such a feature in their docs. There only point where backward chaining is used under the hood, is when you remove triples from the graph, thus, also the inferred materialized triples have to be touched somehow. And to avoid recomputing all inferences, they mix in some backward chaining at one step, see https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/reasoning.html#what-s-in-this-document

Answer (score 1):

GraphDB does forward chaining as your triples are inserted into the database. For backward chaining you'll have to use a different triple store like Stardog, as this isn't an option in GraphDB.